# sinon.js - how to organize my stubs?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm using mocha + sinon.js + chai.
I have many test with a lot of stubs and mocks, so my it() function are too long.
is there any way to organize my stubs in other file/config file.
I cannot put the stubs in before() because each test is stubbing in different way(stub same object but with different behaviour).

any good ideas for me?

tnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [babel-plugin-inline-json](https://github.com/gkatsev/babel-plugin-inline-json) to load json for your response. 
e.g.
Install an configure babel-plugin-inline-json.

```
//.babelrc:
{
  "plugins": [["inline-json", {"matchPattern": "config"}]]
}
```

Define your response in an external file like:

```
//res.config.json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Use it on your tests:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');

class SomeObject {
    doSomething(){
        return null;
    }
}

describe('Some tests:', function () {    
       it.only('With fake response', () => {
        const obj = require('./res.config');
        const someObject = new SomeObject();
        sinon.stub(someObject,'doSomething').returns(obj);

        const res = someObject.doSomething();

        expect(res).to.haveOwnProperty('foo');
        });

    });
});
```

You can have several **config.json** files.